# Ignore h3 tags in an html file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an html file named `file.html`, i get data from it using this code:

```
f = open(file,encoding="utf8")
document = BeautifulSoup(f.read()).get_text()
```

this code returns all the text in the html file, but i want a code that is able to delete titles that are inside h3 tags and get the remaining text.

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` should have function to remove some elements from HTML and you could use it before getting text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code, it should ignore all the h3 tags in your file and treat it later:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("file.html", encoding="utf8"),"html.parser")
clean = []
for tag in soup.find_all('h3'):
    clean.append(tag.text)
 f = open("file.html", encoding="utf8")
document = BeautifulSoup(f.read()).get_text()
for item in clean:
    document = document.replace(item,' ')

print(document)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `item.extract()` or `item.decompose()` to remove item from `soup`.

Eventually you can use `item.clear()` to remove content from item and later HTML will have item but without text.

```
for h3 in soup.find_all('h3'):
    h3.extract()
    #h3.decompose()  
    #h3.clear()
```

---

Minimal working example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div>Hello <h3>other</h3> World <h3>:)</h3><div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print('--- before ---')
print(soup.get_text())

for h3 in soup.find_all('h3'):
    h3.extract()
    #h3.decompose()    
    #h3.clear()

print('--- after ---')
print(soup.get_text())
```

Result:

```
--- before ---
Hello other World :)

--- after ---
Hello  World
```

Documentation: [extract()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract), [decompose()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose), [clear()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#clear)